# Check if an exception was thrown and continue after the exception was thrown

Tags: java, exception, junit, assert, ioexception

I want to make a test that reads from a file some data and passes that data to a function. That function calls other methods and some of them throw some exceptions. I'm interested in how can I check whether or not calling the method with the parameters from the file triggered an IOException somewhere along. I know that the code snippet provided will stop the execution because I've used assert. How should I write if I want to check if an IOException was thrown and if it was, to get the error message, without stopping the execution of the test? Thanks!

```
void test() throws IOException {
    Service service = helperFunction();
    File articles = new File("file.txt");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(articles);
    while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        line = line.replaceAll("[^\\d]", " ");
        line = line.trim();
        line = line.replaceAll(" +", " ");
        String[] numberOnTheLine = line.split(" ");

        List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(numberOnTheLine).map(Integer::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());
        Article article = new Article(Long.valueOf(list.get(0)),
                new HashSet<>(List.of(new Version(list.get(1)))));

        List<List<Article>> listOfArticles = Collections.singletonList(List.of(article));
        Assertions.assertThrows(IOException.class,
                () -> service.etlArticles(listOfArticles.stream().flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList())));
    }
}
```

Comment: Just curious: If an IOException is thrown when opening the file, how would you continue after with no data?

Comment: The exception I'm looking for is an exception triggered by another method that is called in etlArticles. I'm not talking about exceptions connected to the file operations.

Comment: in your question you asked "How should I write if I want to check if an IOException was thrown" then in your response to my comment above, you stated: "I'm not talking about exceptions connected to the file operations". Based on your sample code, this is seemingly contradictory. Can you explain what you are truly trying to debug/fix?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question makes no sense

Answer (score 2):

Simple; a try/catch statement will take care of it.

Replace this:

> ```java
> service.etlArticles(listOfArticles.stream().flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList())));
> ```

With:

```java
try {
 
 service.etlArticles(listOfArticles.stream().flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList())));
} catch (IOException e) {
  // Code jumps to here if an IOException occurs during the execution of anything in the try block
}
```

You are free to e.g. do some logging and then just `Assert.fail`, if you want.

assertThrows is quite simple, all it does is this:

```java
  try {
    runThatCode();
  } catch (Throwable e) {
    if (e instanceof TypeThatShouldBeThrown) {
      // Great, that means the code is working as designed, so, just...
      return;
    }
    // If we get here, an exception was thrown, but it wasn't the right type.
    // Let's just throw it, the test framework will register it as a fail.
    throw e;
  }

  // If we get here, the exception was NOT thrown, and that's bad, so..
  Assert.fail("Expected exception " + expected + " but didn't see it.");
}
```

Now that you know how it works, you can write it yourself and thus add or change or log or whatever you want to do during this process at the right place. However given you know it's `IOException`, instead of an `instanceof` check you can just `catch (IOException e)`, simpler.

Comment: I've already tried this but the method "etlArticles" doesn't have any exception signatures so it won't work with a try and catch...

Comment: @ggtr then it __cannot__ possibly throw that specific exception, unless classfile hackery / versioned compilation shenanigans / non-java (kotlin or scala for example). It can throw, for example, RuntimeException, NumberFormatException, OutOfMemoryError - and you can catch those. If it throws IOEx without declaring, you CAN catch that - catch `Exception`, and use an instanceof  check.